# How do I decode an image bytes sent between two UWP apps using OpenCV?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, uwp, c++-cx

I'm using an UWP AppService to send a png image converted to byte[] from one app (Unity/C#) to an OpenCV app (C++) for image processing. I'm having issues running cv::imdecode on the passed byte[] as the Mat.data member always end up NULL... I'm thinking there might be formatting issues when sending the byte array from C# to C++?

```
        // Get bytes from webcam using Unity's Texture.EncodeToPNG() function
        Byte[] imageBytes = null;
        imageBytes = Communications.GetColorBytes();

        if (imageBytes != null)
        {
            // Convert bytes to BitMapImage to display on XAML
            BitmapImage image = await ImageFromBytes(imageBytes);
            WebcamImage.Source = image;

            //Send a message to the app service
            var inputs = new ValueSet();
            inputs.Add("data", imageBytes);
            AppServiceResponse response = await this.connection.SendMessageAsync(inputs);

            //If the service responded display the message. We're done!
            if (response.Status == AppServiceResponseStatus.Success)
            {
                Byte[] test = response.Message["result"] as Byte[];
                image = await ImageFromBytes(test);
                WebcamImageProcessed.Source = image;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Here's the C++ OpenCV code to decode the sent byte[]

```
    auto input = args->Request->Message;

    Platform::Array<unsigned char>^ inputData = safe_cast<Platform::IBoxArray<unsigned char>^>(input->Lookup("data"))->Value;
    int size = inputData->Length;

    // Create the response
    auto result = ref new ValueSet();

    // decode byte[] and display image on another screen
    auto buf = inputData->Data;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data(buf, buf + size);
    cv::Mat img_scene = cv::imdecode(data, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    if (img_scene.data == NULL) {
        result->Insert("error", 0);
    }
    else {
        cv::namedWindow("Gray image", cv::WindowFlags::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cv::imshow("Gray image", img_scene);

        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using `C++/CX`

Answer (score 0):

Answer: [How to come from C# stream to OpenCV Mat by using c++/cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649136/how-to-come-from-c-sharp-stream-to-opencv-mat-by-using-c-cli)

cv::imdecode had to take in another Matrix for its first paramter

```
        auto buf = inputData->Data;
        cv::Mat img_data1(size, 1, type, buf);
        cv::Mat img_scene = cv::imdecode(img_data1, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```